# Serve multiple local dev servers (vue or react) with nginx

Tags: vue.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a folder called `my-repo` which contains two apps:

```
my-repo/packages/foo
my-repo/packages/bar
```

Let's say I run them locally (vue dev server): `localhost:3000 → foo` and `localhost:4000 → bar`

I want to serve them on `localhost:5000`, such that

```
localhost:5000/foo → localhost:3000 (my-repo/packages/foo)
localhost:5000/bar → localhost:4000 (my-repo/packages/bar)
```

So I have the following config in my `nginx.conf` file:

```yaml
server {
        listen       5000;
        server_name  localhost;

        # this works:
        location / {
            alias /Users/my-user/my-repo/packages/foo; # direct path
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        }

        # this does not work:
        location /foo {
            alias /Users/my-user/my-repo/packages/foo; # absolute path
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        }

        # as expected, this does not work:
        location /bar {
            alias /Users/my-user/my-repo/packages/bar; # absolute path
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
        }
```

I tried all sorts of regex based `try_files and maps` and I could not get it to work. I tried building the projects and serving the `/dist`, I could not get that to work either.

I know there are some options like `baseURL`, or a `homapage` in `package.json`, but I could not set these up either.

Why does the default location `/` work, but not the nested ones?

Comment: what does happen? when you access `localhost:5000/foo` do you reach `nginx` and get an error? if so which error? did you re-start `nginx` after editing the conf file?

Comment: @Itai when I access localhost:5000/foo, I see my index.html, but styles are missing, and paths cannot be found ("localhost:5000/foo/script.js" does not exist, but it actually lives in the `alias` path I specified). I did restart after changing my config. I am pretty sure I am missing a map (path to path) in order for it point to the right directory and serve files

Comment: can you try using the keyword `root` instead of `alias`? also, can you check in your app wether `index.html` is served by it or by nginx?